# Preg_match_all repeated group

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

this is my string:

```
zzzzzzz-------eh="koko"------eh="zizi"--------eh="mimi"--------xxxxxx
```

i need a reg-expression to extract koko, zizi and mimi

but eh='zizi' is optional:
so if it doesn't exist like in :

```
zzzzzzz----------eh="koko"-----------------eh="mimi"----------xxxxxx
```

i should get only koko and mimi.

the '---' are some text.

i tried

```
preg_match_all('#zzzzzzz(.*eh="([^"]*)"){2,3}.*xxxxxx#Uix',  $strg , $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

but it doesn't work.

note: the whole thing is like :

```
zzzzzzz--...--xxxxxxzzzzzzz--...--xxxxxxzzzzzzz--...--xxxxxxzz...
```

i need them grouped

like :

```
array():{
         [0]:array():{
                       [0]:"zizi",
                       [1]:"mimi",
                       [2]:"koko",
                     },
          [1]:array():{
                       [0]:"zizi",
                       [1]:"koko",
                     },
         [2]:array():{
                       [0]:"zizi",
                       [1]:"fofo",
                       [2]:"bingo",
                     },   
}
```

Comment: You mean you need to make sure they are between `zzzzzzzz` and `xxxxxx` ?

Comment: there is many zzzzzzzz<--->xxxxxxzzzzzzzz<--->xxxxxxzzzzzzzz<--->xxxxxx 
contigus But i want to know they belong to which group of zz--xx

Comment: Is it possible to have more than 3 `eh` in one `zzzzzzzz...xxxxxx`?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=eh=")([^"]+)(?=")/', $strg, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sY9wW8)

Comment: @Jerry Yup it happens some times :), Thank you Jerry, problem fixed.

Comment: do you understand what i mean?
the whole thing is like zzzzzzz--...--xxxxxxzzzzzzz--...--xxxxxxzzzzzzz--...--xxxxxx
i want the results grouped

Comment: @user2470545 I can see that, they are all going to be in the `$out` array parameter. What do you need more than that ?

Comment: they will all be in the out but i can't recognize which are in the first zzz---xxx which are in the second zzz---xxx ...ect

Comment: @user2470545 Your request is weird but if you want this information then I suggest to use string functions instead of regular expressions like `substr`.

Comment: explode before using regex maybe !

Comment: @user2470545 What ever you find suitable, I don't work with PHP so I can't help you much with it, but I can help with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by capturing all strings preceded by `="` until a `"` is found:

```
$s='zzzzzzz-------eh="koko"------eh="zizi"--------eh="mimi"--------xxxxxx';
if (preg_match_all('~(?<==")[^"]*~', $s, $arr))
   print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => koko
            [1] => zizi
            [2] => mimi
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = 'zzzzzzz-------eh="koko"------eh="zizi"--------eh="mimi"--------xxxxxxzzzzzzz----------eh="koko"-----------------eh="mimi"----------xxxxxx';
$arr = preg_split('/(?<=x)(?=z)/', $str);
foreach($arr as $s) {
    preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $s, $out);
    $arr_out[] = $out[1];
}
print_r($arr_out);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => koko
            [1] => zizi
            [2] => mimi
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => koko
            [1] => mimi
        )

)
```

Comment: actualy this is a way to do it, but i little dont like the foreach,
because the mecanism is already in a foreach